# Prevent pasting into a data validation cell

Tags: excel, vba

Right now I am able to restrict a user from typing over a data validation cell. But when the user pastes a text from another source onto that data validation cell, it bypasses the check/error message. I dont have any experience in VBA but I've copied and pasted several posted solutions online to no avail.

Comment: You would need to protect the sheet and lock the cells you don't want to be overwritten

Comment: @TimWilliams Should I check the "Protect worksheet and contents of locked cells checkbox and what checkboxes would I need to turn off/on under "Allow all users of this worksheet to:"? In my case I want everything to be the same as a regular worksheet the only difference would be the restriction to pasting for data validation cells.

Comment: @TimWilliams It looks like they will need to provide the password whenever they will edit the data validation cell?

Comment: You need to unlock any cells which need to be editable before protecting the sheet.  By default all cells are locked.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/protect-a-worksheet-3179efdb-1285-4d49-a9c3-f4ca36276de6

Comment: I dont want to lock the cells since I still want the data validation cells to be editable(wherein they pick an option from a dropdown). If I lock the data validation cells then wont they be able to even select an option form the dropdown anymore?

Comment: Sorry on double-checking you can't use sheet protection for this.  Here's a workaround: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2686-excel-drop-down-list-prevent-paste.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Restore Data Validation

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```
Option Explicit

Public Const dvWORKSHEETNAME As String = "Sheet1"
Public Const dvCELLADDRESS As String = "A1"
Public dvCELLVALUE As Variant

Sub RestoreDataValidation( _
        ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim dvCell As Range: Set dvCell = Target.Worksheet.Range(dvCELLADDRESS)
    If Intersect(dvCell, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    If Not ContainsDataValidation(dvCell) Then
    
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        On Error GoTo ClearError
        
        ' Replace the following block with your validation.
        ' Best use the macro recorder while creating it.
        ' For 'Formula1:="1,2,3"' use the appropriate list separator
        ' (e.g. I need semicolons 'Formula1:="1;2;3"').
        With dvCell.Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="1;2;3"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With
        
        dvCell.Value = dvCELLVALUE
    
    End If
    
    dvCELLVALUE = dvCell.Value

SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit
End Sub


Function ContainsDataValidation( _
    ByVal rg As Range) _
As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim dv As Long: dv = rg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeSameValidation).Count
    On Error GoTo 0
    ContainsDataValidation = (dv > 0)
End Function
```

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1`**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    RestoreDataValidation Target
End Sub
```

**`ThisWorkbook` Module**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    dvCELLVALUE = Me.Worksheets(dvWORKSHEETNAME).Range(dvCELLADDRESS).Value
End Sub
```